# Multi thread concurrent process handling

Tags: multithreading

I am using Multithread,total 10 threads but Maximum 3 threads only parallel need to run,Which means one thread runned no need to wait for another thread,but concurrent 3 thread only running How i will get this

Comment: try with a global counter for current running threads, whenever counter<3 run available thread, otherwise wait for a running thread to finish and decrement counter

Comment: Hari, you need to work on your explanation. What are you talking about? Multithreading is a common thing for any programming language.

Comment: you better say what is your actual goal. Do you want to keep room for other threads in your process, restrict parallel access to a database, avoid too fast data generation, or what? And what does your 10 threads do, why can't you use just 3 threads instead?